# Finding an occurence of a string after a certain string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, substring

I'm trying to detect priority of emails (which are stored as plain text in a variable), each email has a 'comments' section and I'm looking to search for terms like 'urgent' or 'high' within the comments area but nowhere else, as these sort of terms are in other places.

So far, what I've been doing was:

```
if (stristr($body, 'Comment: urgent')){
    $urgent = true;
    echo '<b>Urgent.</b>';
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work for cases where 'urgent' is in a sentence like, 'This is urgent'.

How can I search through $body after the substring "Comment:"?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the stripos() function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function - which could do with a new name, takes three parameters.

```
$a being the Start Frame
$b being the End Frame
$s being the full string

$a would be 'Comment: '
$b would be whatever is at the end of your comments section
$s would be the email string
```

return value would be the string inbetween, then run your stripos on the return value.

```
function getMiddle($a, $b, $s) {
    return strstr(substr($s, strpos($s, $a) + strlen($a)), $b, true);
}
```

Example: #Note, the second parameter would need to be specialized to your email#

```
if (stripos(getMiddle('Comments: ', 'Sincerely', $email), 'urgent') === false) {
    echo "URGENT";
}
```

Comment: Luckily I had this for my own needs and just had to modify it minimally for yourself :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regular expression:

```
<?php

$string = 'rweiuowreuiwuier Comment: higewrwre werwrewre high';

if (preg_match('#Comment: (urgent|high)#i',$string)){
    $urgent = true;
    echo '<b>Urgent.</b>';
}
```

However you should consider if someone put inside body `Comment: high` this mail will be also consider as high

Comment: Good Call but a lot of people tend to avoid RegEx as much as possible, hence my solution, see answer; still Voting Up as it is a function answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a string with the function strpos

```
    $mystring = 'Comment: urgent';
    $find_string   = 'urgent';
    $pos = strpos($mystring, $find_string);

if ($pos !== false) {
     echo "I find it!";
} else {
     echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: This does not answer how he should detect only from `Comment: ` forth, thus is not a proper answer. As his string wouldn't just be `Comment: urgent`

Comment: But he want to find Urgent on the "Comment:" string.

Comment: no, 'Comment:' is PART of the string, he wants to find URGENT following that part, not prior to it.